# Recommended way to create many sysfs directories and attributes for a linux device driver

Tags: linux-device-driver, sysfs

I need to create a whole bunch of attributes for a driver, which makes it impractical to allocate them statically (64 directories with 5 attributes each).

It looks like there are multiple ways to create directories in sysfs. One seems to be `sysfs_create_dir_ns()` and the other seems to be creating `struct kobject`s, add them to the sysfs and then add attributes to them.

Is there a recommended (or "best") way to do this?

Comment: It seems to me that doing this is not really recommended or supported at all. If you need something like this, you should probably create sub-devices.

Answer (score 2):

One possible way, which at least works if you only have to create one level of subdirectories, is using a `struct attribute_group`. This structure has a member `name` which - if not NULL - will be used as a directory in which the attributes listed in the attribute group will be inserted.

This does not, however, allow multiple layers of directories, because you don't have matching `kobject`s for the first level created by `sysfs_create_group()`.

Comment: Thx.  This is exactly what I needed to organize my attributes in directories with device_create_with_groups.  Split up the attributes into groups and assign the name member of the struct attribute_group to the subdirectory name.